# Find all value which satisfy multiple keys in Pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I generate a dataframe for a doc created from a text by spacy as follow:

```
test='We walked the walk and still walk it today. Walking brings us great joy.'
tokens=[]
lemma=[]
pos=[]

df=pd.DataFrame()

doc=nlp(test)
for t in doc:
    tokens.append(t.text)
    lemma.append(t.lemma_)
    pos.append(t.pos_)
df['tokens']=tokens
df['lemma']=lemma
df['pos']=pos

df
```

```
     tokens   lemma    pos
0        We  -PRON-   PRON
1    walked    walk   VERB
2       the     the    DET
3      walk    walk   NOUN
4       and     and  CCONJ
5     still   still    ADV
6      walk    walk   VERB
7        it  -PRON-   PRON
8     today   today   NOUN
9         .       .  PUNCT
10  Walking    walk   VERB
11   brings   bring   VERB
12       us  -PRON-   PRON
13    great   great    ADJ
14      joy     joy   NOUN
15        .       .  PUNCT
```

And I group it by ('lemma', 'pos')

```
groups_multipe=df.groupby(['lemma','pos'])
```

I want to find all lemma which own both pos 'VERB' and 'NOUN'. I tried to use `.apply()` and `.fliter()`, but I'm not good at it.

For example, lemma 'walk' satisfies the requirement because it has 'VERB' and 'NOUN' in the column 'pos' at the same time.

How can I achieve it

---

Addition:

Finally, I achieve it in a stupid way: The intersection of sets verb and noun

Here is my code:

```
lemma_v=set(gm[0][0] for gm in groups_multiple if gm[0][1]=='VERB')
lemma_n=set(gm[0][0] for gm in groups_multiple if gm[0][1]=='NOUN')

lemma_vn=list(lemma_v & lemma_n)
```

It's so much inefficient, but I do not know any better way. Somebody has idea to improve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_transform` to create a boolean mask and select right rows:

```
# custom function to check if 'lemma' is in 'VERB' and 'NOUN'
is_verb_and_noun = lambda x: set(x) == set(['VERB', 'NOUN'])

out = df.loc[df.groupby('lemma')['pos'].transform(is_verb_and_noun), 'lemma']
print(out)

# Output:
1     walk
3     walk
6     walk
10    walk
Name: lemma, dtype: object
```

Final output:

```
>>> out.unique().tolist()
['walk']
```

Comment: It's a good method and teach me something about how to use `groupby_transform`. The result, however, will contains duplicates when I use it on my data not the above text. It doesn't matter, using set can remove duplicates easily. Thanks.